# Why isn't the text in this list floating correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have a list.  Each item in the list contains an icon span and text span like so:

```
 <ul id="features">
     <li>
         <span class="icon"></span>
         <span class="text">blah blah blahlrceoahuoa steohuasnoet huntaoheu saoetnhu saoetuhsaoe tuhsaoetnhu saoehtuasoetnhu saou</span>
     </li>            
 </ul>
```

Using the following CSS

```
#features { list-style-type: none; }
#features li { overflow: auto;}
#features li span { float: left;  }
#features .icon { background: #000; height: 55px; width: 55px; display: inline-block;}
#features .text { margin-left: 24px; display: inline-block;  }
```

I believe this code should produce text which floats next to the icon, and automatically adjusts its width accordingly. However this isn't the case [see jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dwZaN/1/)

Why isn't the text floating next to the icon?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/dwZaN/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, trying to make fixed and fluid width live together in harmony... an old problem.

Here's an updated fiddle with the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/dwZaN/11/

```
#features { list-style-type: none; margin-top: 24px; margin-right: 24px; }
#features li { margin-bottom: 24px; overflow: auto; width: 100%; }

#features li span {  }
#features .icon { background: #000; height: 55px; width: 55px; float: left; }
#features .text { padding-left: 75px; display: block; }
```

Basically...

- Float your fixed-width icon
- Don't float your fluid-width element, but give it padding-left with enough room to account for your icon and some buffer room (this automatically gives it 100% and subtracts whatever padding-left you specify)
- Both elements should be block-level. You don't actually need to specify anything for the icon, but your text span needs to be `display: block` (or you can just switch to DIV's which are already block-level)

Also, since you specify a right margin in your parent UL, adding `width: 100%` makes it expand beyond the browser window and creates a horizontal scrollbar. Simply remove it.

Comment: Actually, your solution at the jsfiddle didn't work for me, but your advice did. Are you sure the fiddle works?

Comment: Indeed, I accidentally used an older version of the jsfiddle I as tweaking. Updated the link and code example. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

`width: auto` will instruct the text span to assume as much width as it requires, based on its content. This is what causes the entire span to wrap when that space is not available.

Comment: Ahh... but I've updated the jsfiddle (and question) without the width: auto and I'm still seeing the div.text underneath the icon

Comment: @cosmicbdog: `width: auto` is the default behavior, so simply removing `width` will have the same effect. You need to specify a width manually.

Comment: thanks for explaining that. Perhaps I'm dreaming, but I recall 2 x spans that have a display: inline-block should auto resize to fit each other - I'm trying for a scalable solution here without fixed widths. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a CSS background in the inner element and floating the LI. You do not need a separate element for the icon.

```
#features li { float left }

#features li span { 
      display:block;
      background-image: url(...);
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      height:25px;
      padding-left:30px;
}
```

See my tutorial: [I love lists](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/).

If you want to use a font instead of an image, you can use `position:relative`, on your LI and add:

```
li:before {
    content: "\25A0";   <--- this is a UTF-8 square
    left: -1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.1em;
}
```

(adjust your spacing values accordingly)

Comment: I would normally do that, but I'm using font icons for this current scenario, and not an image :( Unless you know a way to make a background with a font?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do that. I have edited my answer to include this.

Comment: That is creative. I had never thought to do that. It is a good option for next time. Thank you.